# Picasso or Fresco failing to load images

Tags: android, android-imageview, picasso, fresco

I have a project which loads image from server.  I use Picasso like this,

```
Picasso.with(context).load("https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/21/posts/19431/featured_image/CodeFeature.jpg").into(holder.packageImage);
```

But this is not loading this image. I am not getting any error back. I have also tried the Facebook Fresco library . Thats also not working.

I use this code for Fresco,

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/21/posts/19431/featured_image/CodeFeature.jpg");
SimpleDraweeView draweeView = (SimpleDraweeView) findViewById(R.id.sdvImage);
draweeView.setImageURI(imageUri);
```

Whats going wrong here? Is there any way that I can debug this issue or to get more info on this not working either from Fresco or Picasso?

I see this message in Logs when I add the image loading code,

> I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Saying that `Picasso` and `Fresco` are failing trying to load an image and the image really exists is difficult, be sure to set the Internet permission into your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and check the visibility of the view where you are trying to load the image.

Comment: I have already added that, Is there any way that i can get more info in logs?

Comment: @EasyCoder check your LogCat, have you find something there?

Comment: Updated my question wit log , I see this message in the logs I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false

Comment: I fixed the issue using this link https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html. I added the config file to trust all CERTS installed on my device and it started to work.